# How change in loop paramter in URL SoapUI Rest

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I have adress for example: https://stackoverflow.com/1234?action=update?status=active and I would like to '1234' will be changed dynamically in loop so I do:

1. I create REST Project and add url  https://stackoverflow.com/{id}?action=update?status=active  in SoapUI 5.3.0
2. I add id like parameter STYLE = Template, Value = ${id}
3. I create TestCase with REST Request and Groovy Script
4. I add the same Rest Request (URL https://stackoverflow.com/{id}?action=update?status=active and add id like parameter STYLE = Template, Value = ${id})
5. In Groovy Scipt I want to change value of &{id} and go to rest request so I write:

```groovy
def ids= [1,2,3,4]
for(i=0;ids.size();i++){

   context.testCase.getProperty('id') as Integer 
   //How I com back to Rest Request? 
}
```

Do you have any ideas? It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do this by using properties

Name the url like

```
  ${#TestCase#url}
```

Disable the Request whose name is "request1"

Add a **groovy script** through which you will run the request multiple times

Take reference of this step

```
String id[]=["Value1forid","value2","value3","value4","value5")  
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {  
    def temp=" https://stackoverflow.com/{" + id[i] + "}?action=update?status=active "

    testRunner.testCase.setProertyValue("url",temp)
    tstep=testRunner.testCase.gettestStepbyName("request1")
    tstep.run(testRunner,context)
 }

// This way you can run the request 5 times with 5 times different URL where we have put the value we want

// This can be used for any number of properties. Since the request is disabled it will not run and will be run via Groovy step
```

Comment: It was helpful I modify by change only 'id' in loop.

Comment: Thanks you for accepting the solution and also posting your own solution

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
It is possible, I uploaded the project to [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pvfOIQUXHWlgWhz4CZr0ceNjXvblMsn9). I think it might help you.
I followed [this](https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/) guys's tutorial from 2012.
As example, I used swagger's petstore, but you should be able to replace that part to whatever API you need. It doesn't matter whether it's a TEMPLATE or a QUERY parameter - approach stays the same.

[image: Screenshot of the project]

P.S at the moment of creation pets 1,2,3,5, and 6 were present. That's why you can see 1,2,3,5,6 in the input.

Let's say this is the structure of your project:

> 1.DataSource(Groovy step)
>
> 2.Properties
>
> 3.Request(API)
>
> 4.DataLoop(Groovy step)

**This is the contents of DataSource(Groovy step)**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils

def myTestCase = context.testCase
def counter,next,previous,size
def projectDir = new GroovyUtils(context).projectPath

File tickerEnumFile = new File(projectDir + "/input.txt") //make sure input.txt file already exists and contains different set of values sepearted by new line (CR).
List lines = tickerEnumFile.readLines()
size = lines.size.toInteger()
propTestStep = myTestCase.getTestStepByName("Properties") // get the Property TestStep
propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Total", size.toString())
counter = propTestStep.getProperty("Count").value
if (counter == null || counter == ""){
    counter = 0
}
counter= counter.toInteger()
next = (counter > size-2? 0: counter+1)
tempValue = lines[counter]
propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Value", tempValue)
propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Count", next.toString())
next++
log.info "Reading line : ${(counter+1)} / $lines.size"
propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Next", next.toString())
log.info "Value '$tempValue' -- updated in $propTestStep.name"
if (counter == size-1){
propTestStep.setPropertyValue("StopLoop", "T")
log.info "Setting the stoploop property now..."
} else if (counter==0){
def runner = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner(testRunner.testCase, null)
propTestStep.setPropertyValue("StopLoop", "F")
} else{
propTestStep.setPropertyValue("StopLoop", "F")
}
```

**Properties:** Should be empty in the beginning

[image: Properties should be empty in the beginning]

**Request:**

[image]

and finally **DataLoop**:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap

def myTestCase = context.testCase

def runner
propTestStep = myTestCase.getTestStepByName("Properties") // get the Property TestStep
endLoop = propTestStep.getPropertyValue("StopLoop").toString()

if (endLoop.toString() == "T" || endLoop.toString()=="True" || endLoop.toString()=="true"){
log.info ("Exit from the loop")
assert true
} else {
testRunner.gotoStep(0)
}
```

Old comment:
Are you working with free version of SoapUI or SoapUI Pro? Perhaps ReadyAPI? If you are using Pro version, you might want to consider using Data Source Loop. Let me know if that's the case. Thank you.

Comment: I created a SoapUI project you need but not sure I can attach it here.

Comment: @ Gregory Thanks. I resolve my problem use  ${#TestCase#id} and in TestCase I add groovy script which call to restRequest by testRunner.runTestStepByName( "REST_REQUEST")

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problem by add value  ${#TestCase#id} next in groovy script:

```
def ids= [1,2,3,4] 
for(i=0;ids.size();i++){
 String id = ids[i]  
 context.testCase.setPropertyValue("id", ids[i]) 
 testRunner.runTestStepByName( "REST_REQUEST")  
}
```